# PyCharm resolve .egg file

Tags: pycharm, egg

I am having a similar / identical issue to [adding .egg files to the path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205817259-adding-egg-files-to-the-path) , where in the PyCharm IDE it says:

[image: can't resolve reference]

However, from the console I have:

```
In[2]: from scipydirect import minimize
In[3]: import scipydirect 
In[4]: scipydirect.__file__
Out[4]: '/home/user/Documents/InFoMM/bayesian_optimisation/venv2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipydirect-1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipydirect/__init__.pyc'
```

How can I get PyCharm to resolve this issue and find the correct module, and add the `.egg` to my path?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your PyCharm project using different python interpreter. You can check it in `Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`. If it's not using your virtual environment, just click on gear sign, select `Add Local` and choose `/home/user/Documents/InFoMM/bayesian_optimisation/venv2/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

For whatever reason (unknown to me) it was installed okay using `pip` inside my virtual environment, my python console (both from the PyCharm "python console" and the terminal) knew where to look, but it wasn't in the IDE's python path. Re-installing with pip seemed to do the trick.